# LibGDX, How to create a 2d collision terrain

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

How can I create a surface so my bike collides with the ground?[image: See Picture]
I'm thinking of placing x,y coordinates, but that will be too straight and I want it more smooth. (I don't want to place 1 million dots)

Comment: Please mark one of the answers correct if they worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a popular example: the once so famous Hill Climb racing for mobile devices (seriously, everyone and their grandma played this thing).

[image]

If you look at this image from a normal distance (aka. from a distance that doesn't make you go blind in 10 minutes), then this looks insanely smooth. But if you look at it from close up (especially at the valley on the left) you notice, that it's actually out of line segments.

Because the distance between 2 vertex is very small, a normal user doesn't notice it.

You can also make the terrain have more vertices around the parts, where the terrain is more curvy, kind of like how bézier curves work.

Answer (score 1):

Using many small line segments is a good, simple, practical solution, but if you want actual smooth curves that's possible too without much extra effort or processing power.

One easy way to do it would be to use one dimensional bezier curves, also known as explicit bezier curves, but also known as just polynomials.

The formula for a quadratic bezier curve is:

y=A*(1-x)^2+B*2x(1-x)+Cx^2

The values A,B,C are scalar values that control the y value (height) of the curve for the different values of x.

The A value is the height when x is 0, the C value is the height when x is 1.  The B value controls the height in the middle but the curve doesn't pass through that height.

How you can use this information is you can decide that you are going to make a bezier curve control every 10 units on x as an example.

What you do then is if you want to find how high the ground is at a given x location, you divide x by 10 and floor that value (cast to an integer) to get the index of the curve that controls that height.

You then calculate what percentage the x value is on that curve using this formula:

percent = (x-curveIndex*10)/10

That percent value is what you use as the x value in the bezier curve equation to give you the y value which is the height of the terrain.

You can then use that height to know if something is above or below the terrain and take appropriate action.

In practical terms you'll probably want the A and C points to match up with the curves next to them to make the curves continuous and smooth, but it isn't a requirement.

The only other thing I want to mention is that 1d Bezier curves aren't your only option, but they are IMO easier to explain and use compared to other curve choices.

You can read more about 1d bezier curves here:
http://blog.demofox.org/2014/08/28/one-dimensional-bezier-curves/

Comment: You still need to render those curves though. Filling up an area on a bitmap is very impractical on an android devive.

Comment: You can render a quadratic bezier curve efficiently as a single triangle and a simple pixel shader. There are other methods too including coercing bilinear texture sampling to calculate that quadratic polynomial I mentioned.  Link 1: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/loopblinn05.pdf Link 2: http://blog.demofox.org/2016/02/22/gpu-texture-sampler-bezier-curve-evaluation/

Comment: You might also be interested in this, which uses signed distance fields both for rendering smooth curve terrain, as well as doing physics tests against them! https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Msy3WD

Comment: I'm in high school so I haven't really worked with bezier curve yet. Therefore I want a more simple way if you know what I mean. Is it possible to make a background image (the sky) and another layer with the ground displayed on top of it and then make it collide with my bike?

Comment: Filip, don't let the name scare you. What I explained is just a quadratic function where you plug in an x value for the ground and get a y value of height.  You aren't.going to get much simpler than that.

Comment: Iirc a quadratic function needs 4 control points, and time as input (not x), and they return the position for that time.

Comment: Nope, 3 control points for quadratic. It's 4 for cubic. The degree controls how many control points there are. Regarding the position and time.comment, no, that is not strictly true either. Read what I wrote, it covers it.  You can also ask a new question if you want and I can go into more detail.